# Scala define stream with JodaTime

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm just starting my journey with scala. I'm trying to define an implicit conversion that will make it possible to iterate over each day in a period of time in this way:

```
for (day <- firstDay until lastDay) {
  // a lot of interesting code goes here
}
```

What I managed to do so far is something like this:

```
implicit class DateTimeWithUntil(from: DateTime) {
  def until(to: DateTime): Stream[DateTime] =
    from #:: from.plusDays(1)
}
```

What is the way to implement until method? Is the Stream appropriate for this? Or should it be Iterator or Seq? Or other?

Thanks

Comment: Your current code doesn't do anything with the `to` date - it returns an infinite `Stream`. You have to make it stop at the `to` date.

Comment: I tried something like this:       
from #:: (if (DateUtils.isSameDay(from.toDate, to.toDate)) Stream.empty else until(from.plusDays(1)))
but I don't think it's working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
import org.joda.time._

implicit class DateTimeOps (startDt: DateTime) {
  def until(endDt: DateTime) = for(dayNo <- 0 until Days.daysBetween(startDt, endDt).getDays) yield(startDt.plusDays(dayNo))
}

for(day <- new DateTime() until new DateTime().plusDays(10)) println (day)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: BTW, you can be interested in scala wrapper for joda-time. Repo has quite old commits, so I would not like to import it as dependency but you can spy the implementation made so far.

https://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time